# How to perform server to server Google requests

Tags: php, google-oauth

I'm developing a SAAS application with a FE in Vue and an API REST in Symfony as BE.
I have configured all I need in the Google Client Console and the FE throught a JavaScript library performs a user oAuth2 authentication, grant the app, ecc untill get the token end the refresh token.
At this point the FE makes a POST request to my BE to store the tokens in a DB table.
What I want to do now (and what that I was not be able to get infos from Google) is:

- FE asks to get or store resources to my BE (we works only in Drive or Calendar)
- **my BE uses the oAuth information to perform the related request to Google (How???)**
- my BE works the Google response, stores some data if needed and returns a response, eventually with resources infos/links, to my FE

Every informations that I was able to find relates to how to perform an oAuth request but nothing about how to use the tokens.

Thanks to all

Comment: The token goes in the header of each request to the API which needs authentication. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#4.-send-the-access-token-to-an-api.

Comment: That's right but the Authorization header has the following format: Authorization: auth-scheme authorization-parameters so, what is the auth-scheme? Basic, Bearer, ...? When the token is expired (third user tokens are valid for one hour) what is the procedure to rfesh with the refresh token? Those are the information that Google doesn't expose and that I need to know! Google says that is better to use a library to manage authentication but in my use case authentication is performed in FE and API request in BE so it isn't possible to use a library for me ... and I think I'm not the only one!

Comment: It's normally Bearer I would expect.  There are worked examples in various places in the docs (e.g. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#httprest)

Comment: `in my use case authentication is performed in FE and API request in BE`...why? See https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#webserver and https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client

Comment: I read that documents but my BE is an API REST server and it hasn't page rendering possibilities, only FE is capable and I don't want to manage API requests to Google directly from the  FE.

Comment: Are you wanting the API to interact with the user's Google account? Or with the same account every time? In the latter case you can use a Service Account without needing any front-end authentication at all. In the former case though you'd just have to authenticate on the front-end and then pass the auth token and refresh token through to the backend in one of your API requests, and store it somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was simple: just give the token and eventually refresh token to the Google\Client object:

```
private function getClient(ExternalResource $resource) {
  $client = new \Google\Client();
  $client->setAccessToken($resource->getToken());
  $client->setClientId($_ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"]);
  $client->setClientSecret($_ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"]);

  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($resource->getRefreshToken());

    if (!$token || !isset($token["access_token"])) {
      return null;
    }

    $this->externalResourceRepository->updateResource(
      $resource,
      ["token" => $token["access_token"]]
    );
    $client->setAccessToken($resource->getToken());
  }

  return $client;
}
```

Thnks ADyson for help.